# $\sum_{k=1}^n\sin kx=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}2x\right)-\cos\left(n+\frac{1}2\right)x}{2\sin(x/2)},x\neq0,\pm\pi,\pm 2\pi,\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

Maybe I have a trivial question but , Could you tell me how did we get this fact please ?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin kx=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}2x\right)-\cos\left(n+\frac{1}2\right)x}{2\sin(x/2)},x\neq0,\pm\pi,\pm 2\pi,\ldots$$

Comment: You are welcome. But maybe try to do a little bit of research within already answered or respectively asked question on this side before you ask by yourself :)